# I'm unsure if I am using the present perfect continuous correctly here

Tags: present-perfect-progressive

Let's say that I arrived in England one month ago, and I'm going to stay two months longer. If someone asks me where I live, can I say "I've been living in England for one month" despite the fact that I'm going to stay a little bit longer?

Comment: Sure. What you said is a statement of fact up to now, regardless of what happens next.

Comment: It's just emphasises the action of an unfinished action that started in the past and it's still in progress.

Answer (score 1):

Your declarative example sentence is [grammatically correct](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html):

> We use the Present Perfect Continuous to show that something started in the past and has continued up until now.

What happens next, whether you continue to stay or leave, is another story that has no relation to what you previously said.

Answer (score 0):

Future has really nothing to do with it.  Not to mention that it's still uncertain.  So, if the use of Present Perfect Continuous is justified, it would be by the fact that you **now** live [in England], you came to live in England some time ago, and that this situation isn't about to change.

If you are asked in Present Indefinite tense ("where do you live?"), why not use Present Indefinite in your answer?  Perhaps you wanted to allude to the temporariness of your current living conditions...  In which case it's fine, I think.  You could use "visiting" or "staying" instead of "living", of course, but it's not such a big difference.